# Remove unnecessary text?

Tags: php, regex

I currently have this:

```
$population = '1,601 (2001 census){{Census 2001 AUS|id=SSC12856|name=Palm Beach (State Suburb)|accessdate=30 June 2007|quick=on}}';
```

I want this:

```
$population = '1,601 (2001 census)';
```

I've tried using `preg_match` to remove everything after what I want, but I can't figure out the regex.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

Is removing after the first `{` okay?

```
substr($population, 0, strpos($population, '{'))
# This would be better written strtok($population, '{'), as @mario points out.
```

Or, to remove everything between `{{` and `}}`:

```
preg_replace('/{{.*?}}/', '', $population);
```

Comment: Yeah, thats fine! Thanks, didn't think of this.

Comment: another way round would be `if (preg_match('/^([0-9,]+\s+\([\)]+\))/', $str, $m)) $population = $m[1];`

Comment: The `substr`/`strpos` pair can be abbreviated to `strtok($s, '{')`.